# can I return same cell upon dequeing reusable cell if it is not nil?

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

Here is my code to return the cell if it not nil

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
if(cell==nil){
    NSLog(@"cell == nil");
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    cell.tag = device.deviceID;
}else{
    NSLog(@"cell != nil - else part");
    return cell;
}
```

// add my objects to cell

//return cell

Is this right thing to do, that I can return cell at the point when I found cell is already there and I don't want to repaint it ?, which I am doing in my else part

If the cell doesn't exists, I will repaint it and return at the end

Comment: You need to return `cell` regardless, so the return statement shouldn't be in the `else`

Comment: @paulw11 the thing is i want to avoid repainting the same thing, so if the cell already exists I want to return it

Comment: Yes, that is why you dequeue a reusable cell - but cell objects can be reused for different rows, so you always need to reset the content. But as I and the others have said the function must always return a cell.

Comment: @paulw11 please look at my edits

Comment: You **always** need to set the content for your cell, regardless of whether a  n existing cell was returned or you had to create a new cell - the existing cell that was returned was probably used for a different row last time.  Simply delete the `else` part entirely.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to set any data then do that after your if statement (after getting the cell). And there's no need of else part (As this code will be in cellForRow method and you have to return a cell in any case)